# How to Mock Kotlin LifecycleCoroutineScope for Unit Test?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, mockk

How can I mock the following function `act`.

```
class Some {
    internal lateinit var coroutineScope: LifecycleCoroutineScope

    ...

    fun act() {
        coroutineScope.launch {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I am using `mockk` and `kotlinx-coroutines-test` for unit-testing this. But it can only mock `CoroutineScope` and not `LifecycleCoroutineScope`.

Comment: do you need a `LifecycleCoroutineScope` in your code iof you just want to call `launch()`? Probalby a good old  `CoroutineScope` would do the job.

Comment: @Jens Baitinger you are right, if I change it to `CoroutineScope`, the test works. I just wanted to check if I can get `TestLifecycleCoroutineScope` somehow so that I don't have to change the code.

Comment: If you dont need the more sophisticated interface, you should not have a dependency to it. make your code easy to to test, that usually makes it easier to understand. By having a "only" a `CoroutineScope` you tell the reader of your code that in all around your code you will only call the limited functionality of that interface. when you have your dependency to `TestLifecycleCoroutineScope`, the reader of the code needs to thinl about what is special about that interface, why do we need it here, and that makes the code hard to understand